# Animating the updated Binding variable in SwiftUI?

Tags: animation, binding, swiftui, state

How do I give a different animations and transitions to a variable when it's value changes and the view updates?
For example: 
I have a state and binding variable, I want "animation A" for when it's normally displayed, but I want it to have "animation B" for when its value changes.

UPDATE:
Here's a sample code:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var StateVar = {name: "Lily", city: "San Jose"}

    var body: some View {
      ChildView(bindingVar: $StateVar)
      Text("Name: \(StateVar.name)")
      Text("City: \(StateVar.city)")
    }
}
```

===========

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var bindingVar: json

    var body: some View {

      Button(action: {
        bindingVar.city = "Sunnyvale"
      }) {
         Text("Change city name")
      }

    }
}
```

Now if I want transition for `Text("City: \(StateVar.city)")` to be .slide when the ParentView first loads and .scale when it's value changes(in the ChildView), how can I accomplish this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Would you show your code?

Comment: I have added a sample code. Hope it was helpful to understand what I'm trying to ask.